# Can't connect to GCS bucket from Python despite being logged in

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a GCS bucket set up that contains data that I want to access remotely. As per the instructions, I have logged in via `gcloud auth login`, and have confirmed that I have an active, credentialed account via `gcloud auth list`. However, when I try to access my bucket (using the Python google.cloud.storage API), I get the following:

```
HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to <my-bucket-name>.
```

I'm not sure why it is being accessed anonymously, since I am clearly logged in. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the nature of your Python application?  My understanding is that the Python client library has the opportunity to specify a desired set of connection credentials.  It may be explicitly setting credentials (that may be aren't present) as opposed to inheriting your environmental credentials.

Comment: Can you check if the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is set in your python venv?

Comment: This is a simple script running on my local machine, using pandas to load a CSV file stored on GSC. It works fine on my macOS machine (which I thought I had authorized in the same way), but does not work on this Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

The Python GCP library (and others) uses another authentication mechanism than the gcloud command.

Follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) to set up your environment and have access to GCS with Python.

`gcloud aut login` sets up the `gcloud` command tool with **your credentials**.

However, the way forward when executing code, is to have a Service Account. Then, when the env. variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS has been set. Python will use the **Service Account credentials**

**Edit**

```py
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path_to_your_.json_credential_file"
```

**Edit**

And then, to download `gs://my_bucket/my_file.csv` to a file: (from the [python-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/cloud-client))

```py
download_blob('my_bucket', 'my_file.csv', 'local/path/to/file.csv')
```

```py
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name,
        destination_file_name))
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, and in fact the example at the bottom of the page runs and shows the bucket I am trying to access. However, when trying to access its contents using, e.g. `gs://my_bucket/my_file.csv`, I get the anonymous caller error that I originally reported.

Comment: Check my updated answer, if it does not work, you can upload some code to let us see how the error arises.

Comment: Will try this, though on macOS simply calling `pd.read_csv("gs://my_bucket/my_data.csv")` works after the same authentication process.

Comment: Unfortunately it still fails for me, using the functions above. I get a DefaultCredentialsError despite GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to the appropriate json file. Again, works seamlessly on macOS, but fails on Linux,

Comment: The service Account has to have the correct role to access the GCS. The environment variable should not be quoted `"`. Its also a good idea to set up the env. variable on the same code.